# MVC server side validation conflicts with client side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

With ASP.NET MVC 5, how can one mix server side business rules and logic with client side basic validation?  Specifically, using @Html.ValidationMessageFor()?

Here's a common scenario; imagine a login form with username + password.  The username has to be an email address, and is of course required.  So you have a model with Data Annotations of [Required] and [EmailAddress] on the username field, but when you submit your form to the controller, you check to see if that email address is a valid user/email address registered at your site.  If it is not, you might do something like:

```
ModelState.AddModelError( "Username", "This username isn't registered at this site.")
```

Unfortunately, when that goes back to the view, client side unobtrusive validation sees that your field has a valid email address in it, so it removes your custom server side supplied error at page load!  (Evidently MS' implementation of jquery validate does an automatic validation on page load.)

This seems to create a conflict with a very common scenario of additional server side validation rules... and due to client design requirements, we can't simply put the message into a ValidationSummary -- so please, don't suggest that. We need the messages to appear in their place under the fields themselves, where the other normal 'required' and 'must be an email address' validation messages would appear.

Finally, this is just one example of a business logic validation rule; there are more -- custom validation data attributes are likewise not a valid option for everything, and neither is remove (ajax) validation!

Seems like a fairly significant oversight?

Comment: Please consider editing you question to be more concise

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are asking or what you are expecting as an answer. For any specific problem you are having please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I don't know how to make the question any clearer; the first sentence asks the question and then I go into a specific example with a login form.

Comment: it doesn't work like that for me (client validation doesn't remove the server one); for example here: http://prodinner.aspnetawesome.com click on an edit button for a dinner, remove all the meals, you'll get the client side validation (required); select more than 10 meals, click submit and you'll get the server validation

Comment: @Omu interesting... so you're setting your server side validation the same way, using ModelState.AddModelError(), specifying your model property, the error message, and using @Html.ValidationMessageFor() for that same property? I'm trying to figure out potential reasons mine would be different than yours and can't come up with anything.

Comment: yes, all standard validation, you can download the source code

Comment: It does not _remove your custom server side supplied error at page load_ and if your not seeing the error message, then your have other code causing the issue.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: It hides / removes it because at page load, the document is parsed and checked for validity.  Because client side rules are saying "this is required, and there is a value", and "this must be an email address, and yup, there is a email address in here", it removes the custom server side only error message added through ModelState.AddModelError().  It's a fact; I've traced and breakpointed the MS unobtrusive source code and watched it do it.

Comment: @BuddWright, No it will not. And [here is a DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ra1MiT) to prove it. If its not displaying the message for you, it because of other code you have that you have not shown us. Enter a valid email address and save - the error message is displayed.